# Safari bug when with transform you combine rotate and translate

Tags: css, safari, rotation, transform, mobile-safari

I need to make a spin wheel and so far it work well in chrome on responsive etc but the probleme is taht on responsive i have to center the wheel and i use transform translate(-50%) and combine it with a rotate(360 * 3 + randomNumber(0 -- 360)) to get a decend spin on the wheel and a random target on the wheel.

On chrome i works fine, thje wheel make her turns but on mobile safari, it only make a little turn corresponding to the "randomNumber(0 -- 360)"

Here is the code, simplified with an hover because the real project is a bit more "messy" and the bug also exist on hover

```css
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    background: #444444;
}

.spin{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    transition: 6s ease;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.spin:hover{
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(1100deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(1100deg);
}
```

if you want to try at home here i have set 1100 deg to test but the wheel will only make 20deg of spin in 6s because 1100 - 360 * 3 = 20deg

Hope someone got the solution, thank you all

Comment: If you found any solution, please share it with us here, thanks